# C return value using argument to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to run function which will return two strings by passing a pointer to them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gen_str(char *str1, char *str2){
   char *s1 = "abcd";
   char *s2 = "defg";
   str1= strdup(s1);
   str2= strdup(s2);
   printf("\n\r str1 %s str2 %s\n\r", str1, str2);
}


int main(void){
   char *s1, *s2;
   gen_str(s1, s2);
   printf("\n\r s1 %s s2 %s\n\r", s1, s2);
   return 0;
}
```

where output is:

```
str1 abcd str2 defg


 s1 8, s2 8,
```

Can someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong? I thought that strdup() will alloc memory for my new strings, and return pointers filled with strings. But actual behavior is different. So I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got your pointers confused. The *basic type* for a C string is already `char*`, and now you want a pointer *to that*, i.e. a `char**`:

```
void fill_me(char ** ps)
{
  const char * t = "hello";
  *ps = strdup(t);
}

/* elsewhere */
char * s;
fill_me(&s);
```

Moral: If you want a function to modify an argument passed by the caller, the caller needs to take the address-of (`&`) something at some point.

Answer (score 6):

You need your function to modify the pointers `s1` and `s2`, so you need to pass their *addresses*, so that the function can modify the originals, not a copy.

```
void gen_str(char **str1, char **str2){
   char *s1 = "abcd";
   char *s2 = "defg";
   *str1= strdup(s1);
   *str2= strdup(s2);
   printf("\n\r str1 %s str2 %s\n\r", *str1, *str2);
}


int main(void){
   char *s1, *s2;
   gen_str(&s1, &s2);
   printf("\n\r s1 %s s2 %s\n\r", s1, s2);
   return 0;
}
```

Note also that you need to `free` these strings at some point, otherwise you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You're only changing the pointer inside the function. To change it outside the function, you'll need to pass the function the address of the two strings, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gen_str(char **str1, char **str2){
   char *s1 = "abcd";
   char *s2 = "defg";
   *str1= strdup(s1);
   *str2= strdup(s2);
   printf("\n\r str1 %s str2 %s\n\r", *str1, *str2);
}


int main(void){
   char *s1, *s2;
   gen_str(&s1, &s2);
   printf("\n\r s1 %s s2 %s\n\r", s1, s2);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can's use the value of a variable before you've initialized it!

```
   char *s1, *s2;
   gen_str(s1, s2);
```

The first line doesn't assign any particular values to `s1` and `s2`. But then you pass them to `gen_str`. To have another function fill in the value of a variable, pass a pointer to that variable to the function, not its value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void gen_str(char **str1, char **str2){
   const char *s1 = "abcd";
   const char *s2 = "defg";
   *str1 = strdup(s1);
   *str2 = strdup(s2);
   printf("\n str1 %s str2 %s\n", *str1, *str2);
}


int main(void){
   char *s1, *s2;
   gen_str(&s1, &s2);
   printf("\n s1 %s s2 %s\n", s1, s2);
   free(s1);
   free(s2);
   return 0;
}
```